# Fill textarea ckeditor with select box

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I'm trying to change the value of the `textarea` every time I change my `select`. But the ckeditor does not allow this change, only works in a normal `textarea`. What might be happening?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B4yGJ/426/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CKEDITOR.instances.<textarea-reference>`. Here is a [refernece](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Getting-CKEDITOR-instance)

Here is how you do it.

```
$("#abc").on('change', function() {
    CKEDITOR.instances.cde.setData( $(this).val() );
}).change();
```

Here is the updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/B4yGJ/428/)